# How to give name while creating Typography in Design Systems?

Tags: usability, user-expectation, user-research, typography, design-system

**How to give name** while creating Typography in Design Systems?

which of the following is most common when naming typography?

1. System default typography naming.
   (or)
2. Create your own set of naming.

While going with the system default, that time we need 2 to 4(Android, iOS, PC, etc…) sets of different naming in our design system, and hard for the development team to handle.

If you use the second option, it seems you'd run into cases where platform-related rules don't fit.  But we can use a common name inside of our design system and easy to handle for a development team.

**Suggest how to set a common name in Typography in Design Systems.**

Comment: You might need to provide a little more detail or examples to get an answer to this question. For example, what do you mean by "naming typography?"

Comment: Like in web H1 H2... in iOS HUGETITLE, TITLE1, TITLE2... in android DISPLAY1, DISPLAY2.... As we have different names in different platform, I thought to unify in design system for easy understanding purpose.